# Is there evidence that Venator's duel bridge system was inspired by HMS Queen Elizabeth (or vice versa)?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, behind-the-scenes

Both the Venator-Class star destroyer from *Star Wars* and the British Navy's new H.M.S. *Queen Elizabeth* share a common design feature, namely two separate structures for the control of the ship and of the aircraft (or in the case of the Venator) spacecraft stored aboard. I was wondering if this is a coincidence or if this is another example of *Star Wars* taking inspiration from real life.

The aircraft carrier wasn't even ordered until 2007 however, so it would seem unlikely that the dual bridges of the Venator were inspired by this unless the bridge started as just an aesthetic choice and the in universe explanation was only given later (there is also the slim possibility that the engineers of the Elizabeth watched the prequels and thought "Hey that's how we should do it!").

Is there any actual evidence of any causal link between the two in the form of interviews or commentaries or anything or am I just reaching?

Comment: The twin bridge on HMS QE is due to the exhaust is between them. Engineering solution to present tech limitations.

Comment: @Naib No, it would be crazy to design the entire superstructure around some exhaust stacks which could easily be rerouted. Ummdustry is correct in that each tower serves a different purpose; one is for control of the ship, while the other deals with aircraft operations.

Comment: @Cooper I was stating FACT not some supposition. https://ukdefencejournal.org.uk/hms-queen-elizabeth-two-islands/  " The reason for two islands is, simply put, due to the gas turbine exhausts. The design would have either had two small islands or one large, long island.

The two smaller islands were chosen. The location and alignment of the islands are based around the 2.4 metre diameter gas turbine exhausts which were pre-fitted in the island and below in the ship superstructure."     ONCE the design was forced down this route, this split was taken advantage of w.r.t. redundancy, radar etc.

Comment: "The design would have either had two small islands or one large, long island. The two smaller islands were chosen." This decision in itself had nothing two do with the exhausts. Once the decision was made however, the exact location and alignment of the towers was adjusted to fit around the turbine exhausts.